# How to parse .ini file source like objects

Tags: php, oop, object, ini

Is there a way to parse an .ini file with the settings callable as objects?

```
$config = parse_ini_file(ABSPATH . '/config.ini', true);

$dbName = $config->database->name;

//instead of
$dbName = $config['database']['name'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
$config = json_decode(json_encode($config));
```

And now you can use syntax like this.

```
 $dbName = $config->database->name
```